# Redirect admin 403 "Cheatin uh?" admin pages

Tags: admin, users, user-roles, capabilities, user-access

Blocking role capabilities on the admin returns the 403 *"Cheatin Uh?"* page.

What is the best way to redirect this to 403 page to perhaps the dashboard, homepage, or a custom 403 page?

I know I could probably achieve this using .htaccess, but I'd prefer to stick with php / wordpress related functions.

For example something like this:

```
function dont_show_cheatin_page() {
    if ( current_user_can('do_not_allow') ) {
      wp_redirect( admin_url( )); // custom redirect instead of Cheatin 403 page
      exit;
    }
} 
add_action('admin_menu', 'dont_show_cheatin_page');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [this](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/77e365efbf2e499e2ed11d29c101ea466cf1ceed/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L342) is what you're running into.

[admin_page_access_denied](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_page_access_denied) may be the hook you want to use for this.

try

```
function dont_show_cheatin_page() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'do_not_allow' ) ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( admin_url()); // custom redirect instead of Cheatin 403 page
      exit;
    }
} 
add_action('admin_page_access_denied', 'dont_show_cheatin_page');
```

Comment: Haven't been able to try it yet but this looks like it should work! Great find. Never knew about that hook before.